# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined typescript

Tags: arrays, angular

I am trying to push a date object into an array and I get this error "cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

```
export class CalendarComponent { 
days: Date[]

showMonths() {

 const interval = new Interval();

    interval.fromMonth  = this.selectedFromMonth.number;
    interval.fromYear = this.selectedFromYear.number;
    interval.toMonth = this.selectedToMonth.number;
    interval.toYear = this.selectedToYear.number;

    for (let i = interval.fromMonth - 1; i < 11; i++) {
      const day = new Date(interval.fromYear, i, 1);
       this.days.push(day);
      // console.log(day);
      // days.push(day);
    }

    // console.log(day);
}
```

Why do I get this error if 'days' it is already an array and 'day' it is not undefined ?

Comment: You've given it a *type* but not a *value*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initialize your property. You have just set the type of it, but actually it is `undefined`.

```
days: Date[] = [];
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you

Answer (score 1):

static typing is typescript future and when you compile your code to javascript typing will gone this just a help to developer during the build time.

`days: Date[]`  is the same you sa `days` and the **initial value is undefined**

```
var days;

console.log(days); // => undefined
```

that why you need assaign days to `[]` empty array before you use it

```
days: Date[] = [];
```